# Mediawiki's Image Gallery CSS

Tags: css, gallery, mediawiki

Does anyone know where to find the CSS for Mediawiki's image gallery? (Its gallery, the thumbnails, the borders around the thumbnails, etc.) I've looked through a fresh installation and keep finding duplicate copies of it spread throughout the different CSS files. When I try to edit each of them, it doesn't change the pages at all. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You will find them in the [/common/shared.css](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/gitweb?p=mediawiki/core.git;a=blob;f=skins/common/shared.css;hb=HEAD#l754) and [/common/commonContent.css](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/gitweb?p=mediawiki/core.git;a=blob;f=skins/common/commonContent.css;hb=HEAD) files. However, I'd recommend not to edit them there but to overwrite them from the skin files.

Comment: Do you know which skin file the CSS would be in? I'm using Monobook. Thank you for your reply! :)

Comment: You ask for [monobooks main.css](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/gitweb?p=mediawiki/core.git;a=blob;f=skins/monobook/main.css)?